# LogOff Issue: The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have following `LogOff` Function in `AccountController`:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    Session.Remove("UserName");
    Session.Remove("UserRoleId"); 
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.Clear();
    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

Now suppose I have two browser tab is opened. If I logoff from first page , it is working fine.Now after successfully logoff , If I again click Logoff button from second window , it shows me the error:
"**The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user.**"

> I know this question already asked by many users , but those answers
>   didn't solve my problem.I also used `Session.Abandon()` here.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour, but instead of using `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` you could manually handle in code with `AntiForgery.Validate()`

Comment: You see this a lot when the user uses the back button after logging out or posting a form so worth handling gracefully for the user as it is correct behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is exactly what should happen. Second user has nothing to log out from since he is already logged out. So that's fine.

Your problem is customizing error shown to the user. You definitely want to show some custom message giving user more info and less technical details.

In order to do that you need some exception handler and in it handle `HttpAntiForgeryException`.

Comment: Thanks . Your suggession helps for me.I added the code in customerrorattribte   if (ex is HttpAntiForgeryException)
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login");
                }

Answer (score 0):

Its working properly as it should all you now need t do is a try catch check and then on this scenario redirect the user to login page